# LiteoDB and var List inserts C#

Tags: c#, litedb

I'm trying to use LiteDB, I have the following:

```
var list2 = new List<Values>();
```

I've been looking at the LiteDB examples which is the following:

```
// Get customer collection
var col = db.GetCollection<Customer>("customers");

var customer = new Customer { Id = 1, Name = "John Doe" };

// Insert new customer document
col.Insert(customer);

// Update a document inside a collection
customer.Name = "Joana Doe";

col.Update(customer);

// Index document using a document property
col.EnsureIndex(x => x.Name);
```

Is there any way I can insert a list of type Values in my case it would be: var list2 = new List();

I can't seem to find anywhere that inserts this way.

Thanks,

Comment: I dunno.  Is there an overload on the collection's Insert method that takes an IEnumerable<T>?  What about a "BulkInsert" or similarly named method? Intellisense should tell you the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me!!

```
var col = db.GetCollection<Values>("customers");
col.Insert(list2);
```

Thanks,